# Picture won't go into div

Tags: css, html

I've made a wrapper div with a text div and a image div floating to the right. A simple task, yes, but not for me tonight it seems. I am unable to make it work and stuck.

Here's how it looks right now: http://bit.ly/RNinCm

CSS:

```
introwrapper {
    width: 938px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.introtekst {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #a81c11;
}

.gammeltbilde {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="introwrapper">
        <div class="introtekst">
            <p>Some text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gammeltbilde">
            <img src="bilder/kjiptbilde.jpg" alt="bilde fra parken"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS like so:

```
.introtekst {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #a81c11;
    display:inline;
    width: 80%; /* or dependent on what you like */
    float: left;
} 

.gammeltbilde {
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    width: 20%; /* relative to width for introtekst */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture is larger than the container, try setting dimensions on the image:

```
<img src="bilder/kjiptbilde.jpg" alt="bilde fra parken" width="800" />
```

(800 makes it fit, but you may want to change that as needed.)

Comment: regardless of which size I give it still doesn't go into the container I intend. I've tried 800 (very large) and 20.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a `width="800px"` tag on the img, but I would recommend actually staying away from that whenever possible and actually sizing down the images in Photoshop or some similar program. If you have a page with lots of images that you've sized down using the `width` tag, your page load times can get pretty big.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `<img src="bilder/kjiptbilde.jpg" alt="bilde fra parken">`

Comment: :D
The purpose of what? Assignment4?